# appending a string value to remaining rows in a column based on Guid using KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring

**Appending a string value to remaining rows in a column based on Guid using KQL**

Hi,
I have the json data like below

Properties column

```
{"State":"Received","NotificationId":"abc"}
{"State":"Queued","NotificationId":"abc"}
{"State":"Published","NotificationId":"abc", "Short": "tim"}

{"State":"Received","NotificationId":"def"}
{"State":"Queued","NotificationId":"def"}
{"State":"Published","NotificationId":"def", "Short": "mit"}
```

Using parse_json() i managed to parse it and extracted the info from it. I am trying to add Short value ("Short": "tim") to other json values based on NotificationId ("NotificationId":"abc") . Tried different functions. But so far no luck. could u guys please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
datatable(Properties:string)
[
    '{"State":"Received","NotificationId":"abc"}',
    '{"State":"Queued","NotificationId":"abc"}',
    '{"State":"Published","NotificationId":"abc", "Short": "tim"}',
    '{"State":"Received","NotificationId":"def"}',
    '{"State":"Queued","NotificationId":"def"}',
    '{"State":"Published","NotificationId":"def", "Short": "mit"}'
]
| extend d= parse_json(Properties)
| extend State= d.State, NotificationId= d.NotificationId, Short=d.Short
| extend Short= iif(NotificationId=='abc','tim',Short)
| project State,NotificationId,Short
| extend Properties = pack_all(true)
| project Properties
```

This code parses the JSON data using `parse_json()`function and extracts the "State", "NotificationId", and "Short" fields into separate columns. Then, it conditionally replaces the "Short" value with "tim" when the "NotificationId" is "abc" using `iif` operator. Finally,all the columns are packed back into a single "Properties" column using `pack_all()`.

[demo](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VQzWrDMAy+5ymEL07B7AECeYBeRrceyyiOrazq0jjYyhi0e/fZ7iFpWAu1DxbS92dZzfE2HZYb7wb0TBiqwJ76z1WxKyAeeRbbCEJRiXc0SN9ohRKvjqklo5lcv7ZxphsjfqVaUt5GHJ8ibMamo3C4z1EgtgfnWVQgmE7/aTzKabF9LucdwsOciTPPeSKOGsVHcQH8Yewt2BoG7QPuj8H1s+WvJkh2qsG+5ELBrUsa3HYUZL86EtI7E8ptIGrLhUYt40alknGPUmVY8h+8O6LhawC1MFloT8kh/ch87XXXlexHnCtNqD8M9WNjcQIAAA==)